# Typescript 2.4.1 and stricter generics breaking typeof/inheritance

Tags: typescript, generics, typeof

I have this typescript code, using generics that used to work under typescript 2.3, but now breaks under the stricter typing enforcements of typescript 2.4.1.

I wrote this minimal code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
function helloA(clazz: typeof A) {}
helloA(B); // fine

class C<T> {
    private c: T;
};
class D extends C<string> {}
function helloC(clazz: typeof C) {}
helloC(D); // breaks
```

The error from tsc 2.4.1 below:

```
test.ts(11,8): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof D' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof C'.
  Type 'D' is not assignable to type 'C<T>'.
    Types of property 'c' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

So helloA(B) works, and helloC(D) that used to work, now breaks (if I add "noStrictGenericChecks": true to my tsconfig, of course it compiles).

If I remove the `private c: T;` part, it compiles as well. Note that in my actual code, this class member actually exists but the class I extend is from an external library, so I can't remove it, and besides, I'd like it to compile with it.

Is there any way to make this code compile and retain the string typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there's any way to use `typeof C` that doesn't infer `{}` as the generic type parameter.  Luckily, you can refer to a class constructor in a different way:

```
type Constructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
  readonly prototype: T;
}

function helloC<T>(clazz: Constructor<C<T>>) { }
helloC(D);
```

You can see by inspecting the call to `helloC` that it infers `string` as the type parameter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a very smart solution, and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!